# Create android menu via set on click listener

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I want create list menu simple : About , Contact us And more ( about 30-40 button )

After click on this buttons , i want start new activity

I want this code in use class and out of mainactivity

My xml code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3moSl.png

clcAbout , clcContact and clcFB my buttons create by linearlayout

Thx

Comment: What is your question? You want us to code for you?

Comment: @Longi , No in want help me for this question

Comment: You want to start another activity from a class outside your Activity?
You can pass your activities context to the class and then you can start a new activity intent within that class using your context.

example:
`public class myClass{
             private Context mContext;

             public class myClass(Context mContext){
                this.mContext = mContext;
             }

             public void handleOnClick(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, OtherActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
             }`

Comment: @Furedal , My question for setonclicklistener for buttons ( i understand use setonclicklistener for multiple buttons )

Comment: So you want to set your onClickListeners inside a custom class?

If so, you can pass the view of your content to your class and then use findViewById on that view to get your buttons from there.

Comment: @Furedal , i want create multiple buttons and setonclicklistener for all buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public void setUpButtons(final Context context){
    Button clc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clcFB);
    clc.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(0, this));

    // etc...
}

private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    private int index;
    private Context context;
    public void MyOnClickListener(int index, Context context){
        this.index = index;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent;
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity0.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity1.class);
                break;
                // etc...
        }
        if(intent != null){
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the lack of a context variable for creating the intent, you have to previously pass a context (as a parameter for the constructor for example) to that class out of mainactivity then use that context variable in the Intent constructor, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mycontext, (activity class name).class);
mycontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Edit: For OnClickListeners (I'm not sure I know what you want to do though):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, (activity class name).class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```